# Can Neymann-Pearson lemma be applied if two hypothesis are made that one in distribution is discrete and another is continuous?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance

I encountered the following problem:

Consider a hypothesis testing:

Under null hypothesis, the population distribution obeys **Poisson($\lambda$)**, where $\lambda \in [1,6]$.

Under the alternative hypothesis, the population distribution obeys **N($\mu $,10)**, where $\mu \in [1,6]$.

1. If $(X_{1},X_{2},X_{3})$ is a random sample from the population distribution, whether exists Most Powerful Test at level of significant less than or equal to $\alpha = 0.05$ ?
2. If it exists, please find the power.

I am confused by the fact that the two hypotheses are not of the same type of distribution, so I wonder if I can use Neyman Pearson lemma?

I have tried to solve it by lemma, but I can't figure out how to simplify the rejection set.

I'm new to posting and writing mathematical symbols, so I am sorry if you have the poor viewing.

Thanks and regards

Comment: This is a strange question because if you observe three integers the null is true and else it is not.